# Chunking ffmpeg Data on basis of size of video

Tags: hadoop, video, ffmpeg, size, chunks

I am currently chunk live streams like

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://10.100.0.55:8080/live/cam1 -fs 10485760 -f avi - | hadoop fs -put - /tmp/data/vid4.avi
```

I want to make continuous chunks of 10 MB of live stream. So I am planning to run this command in loop but when second time in loop there 1-2 second connection lag & I am loosing 1-2 frames. Will it possible to get continuous chunks of live stream using ffmpeg ?

Comment: ffmpeg has "segment" muxer that might help

Comment: Can chunking of video into HDFS by using FFMpeg Segment muxer is possible ?DO you have any idea?